# How to to create search index submenu w/ v2.3.1 & up

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon, fauxton

I've been watching Fauxton tutorials that were created less than a year ago and noticed they have an option to view indexes under Design Documents. How does one configure Fauxton to show these so I too can create create/add search indexes or has this feature been removed?

[image]

Comment: That screen shot looks like it comes from Cloudant. Are you using Cloudant, or the stock Fauxton? There may well be some differences between them.

Comment: That might also be the result of creating an index for a Mongo query. See [this documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html#db-index).  (This is a guess on my part)